# Rails and unexisting parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api

I have a code like this:

```
User.create(params[:user])
```

But if someone sends params through API like

```
{"userr":{"name":"Firstname"}}
```

then I get 500 error because of undefined method *** for nil:NilClass. How should I handle this and should I at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you should handle false input - this is a situation which might happen in production as well.

I'd simply do:

```
if params[:user].blank?
  # Handle false input here
else
  User.create(params[:user])
end
```

Comment: How does the number of controllers affect your input verification?

Comment: It affects the time to add this verification. Isn't there any possibility to do it once?